# Nginx Proxy pass to s3 for js files returns 400 Bad request

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, proxypass

Below is my nginx configuration.

```
    server_name  myserver.com;

    location ~ /(in|sr)/(en|tm)/(.+\.(css|js)) {
        proxy_set_header Host http://mybucketabc.s3.amazonaws.com;

        proxy_http_version     1.1;
        proxy_set_header       Connection "";
        proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-meta-server-side-encryption;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-server-side-encryption;
        proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
        proxy_ignore_headers   Set-Cookie;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        add_header             Cache-Control max-age=31536000;

        rewrite ^/(in|sr)/(en|tm)/(.*) /$1/$2/$3 break;
        proxy_pass    http://mybucketabc.s3.amazonaws.com;
    }
```

When I try to access http://myserver.com/in/en/main.9bd9926d.js, I'm getting "400 Bad Request"

But directly accessing http://mybucketabc.s3.amazonaws.com/in/en/main.9bd9926d.js works fine.

I've similar proxy pass rules for html and svg files, both works fine but requests to .js files always throws "400 Bad Request".

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried making a simpler location with the bare minimum of directives and slowly adding back in directives? I do something similar with just proxy_pass, proxy_intercept_errors, and recursive_error_pages

Comment: That attempt helped me to resolve the issue. It was happening due wrong Host.         proxy_set_header Host http://mybucketabc.s3.amazonaws.com; "http://" got added in the host by mistake. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This got resolved after correcting the Host.

Wrong Host
        proxy_set_header Host http://mybucketabc.s3.amazonaws.com;

Correct Host (removed "http://")
        proxy_set_header Host mybucketabc.s3.amazonaws.com;